# Qt license my program

Tags: qt

Я собираюсь сделать оболочку для Qt.
То есть вам нужно сначала установить мою оболочку, затем откройте ее и зайдите в настройки там, чтобы указать папку, в которой хранится qt.

Позволит ли мне это лицензия qt, моя оболочка будет коммерческой!

Comment: А оболочка на чем будет написана и с какой лицензией? :)

Comment: С комерчерской 25 бачей за копию программы

Comment: Оболочка будет написана на qt c++ и delphi для некоторых задач

Answer (score 2):

Существует два варианта Qt: бесплатный (лицензия GNU LGPLv3) и платный (специальная лицензия).

Насколько я понимаю, вас интересует именно бесплатный вариант. Согласно условиям LGPL, вы можете распространять свою программу под любой лицензией без ограничений, если при использовании Qt-ных библиотек вы соблюдаете три условия:

1. Qt должен использоваться только в виде динамических библиотек. То есть вы не можете взять исходный код Qt и скопировать его к себе или встраивать Qt-ные *.cpp-файлы в проект.
2. Вы должны указывать, что используете Qt и давать ссылку на официальный сайт (https://www.qt.io/).
3. Если вы используете не оригинальный Qt, а модифицированную версию, вы должны предоставить исходные коды этой версии.

Согласно тому, что вы указали в вопросе, вам необходимо внимательно отнестись только ко второму пункту списка. Его можно соблюсти, добавив в окно «О программе» строку типа:

> Данная программа использует фреймворк Qt (https://www.qt.io/) версии *такой-то*, распространяемый по условиям лицензии GNU LGPLv3.